# I have a problem in Python Overriding class inheritance?

Tags: python, class, inheritance, overriding

I have The parent class Shape

```py
class Shape:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def getArea(self):
        raise Exception('Override the method getArea')

    def printArea(self):
        if not hasattr(self, 'name'):
            raise Exception('Your class is still invalid.')

        print("The area of the current", self.name.lower(), "is", self.getArea())
```

i create a class Triangle that overrides the getArea()

```py
# Sample Triangle class
class Triangle(Shape):
    def __init__(self, b, h):
        super().__init__()
        self.name = 'Triangle'
        self.b = b
        self.h = h

    def getArea(self):
        return 0.5 * self.b * self.h
```

same as Triangle

```
class Parallelogram(Shape):
    def __init__(self, w, h):
        super().__init__()
        self.name = 'Parallelogram'
        self.w = w
        self.h = h

    def getArea(self):
        return self.w * self.h
```

The Rectangle parents should be Parallelogram

```py
class Rectangle(Parallelogram):
    def __init__(self, w, h):
        self.name = 'Rectangle'
        self.w = w
        self.h = h
```

Here is the problem i instantiate the `Square` class with one only parameter and the parent should be `Rectangle`
the `Square` constructor parameter should have `self` and `w` only

```
class Square(Rectangle):
    def __init__(self, w):
        self.name = 'Square'
        self.w = w
```

```
square = Square(11)
square.printArea()
```

when overriding the function here i got an error

```
The Square class Has no Attribute name "h"
```

the expected output of the square should be:

```
The area of the current square is 121
```

Comment: `getArea ` is `self.w * self.h`. How is that going to happen with an `h`? Maybe you should set the square h as well: `self.h = w`. It also seems like `Rectangle` should call `super().__init__(w, h)` to avoid duplicate code. `Square` could call `super().__init__(w, w)`.

Comment: You can set `self.h = w` in your `Square` class, or you can redefine `getArea` in that class to square `self.w`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you need to do the `super.__init__` for all of the subclasses and let the parent class handle assignment of the instance variables it knows about. For instance `Rectangle` should not set the parent classes w and h, it doesn't know if the parent did some processing on those values. And since `Square` doesn't reimplement `getArea` it had better have called super's init to set the variables correctly.

Following is your program with `super().__init__` modifications on rectangle and square.

```
class Shape:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def getArea(self):
        raise Exception('Override the method getArea')

    def printArea(self):
        if not hasattr(self, 'name'):
            raise Exception('Your class is still invalid.')

        print("The area of the current", self.name.lower(), "is", self.getArea())

# Sample Triangle class
class Triangle(Shape):
    def __init__(self, b, h):
        super().__init__()
        self.name = 'Triangle'
        self.b = b
        self.h = h

    def getArea(self):
        return 0.5 * self.b * self.h

class Parallelogram(Shape):
    def __init__(self, w, h):
        super().__init__()
        self.name = 'Parallelogram'
        self.w = w
        self.h = h

    def getArea(self):
        return self.w * self.h

class Rectangle(Parallelogram):
    def __init__(self, w, h):
        super().__init__(w, h)
        self.name = 'Rectangle'

class Square(Rectangle):
    def __init__(self, w):
        super().__init__(w, w)
        self.name = 'Square'

square = Square(11)
square.printArea()
```

Answer (score 1):

does this work?

```
class Square(Rectangle):
    def __init__(self, w):
        self.name = 'Square'
        self.w = w
        self.h = w
```

edit: too slow! didnt read the comments!

Answer (score 0):

Override `getArea` in `Square`:

```
def getArea(self):
    return self.w ** 2
```